# .NET Maui Button dentro de un control personalizado no llama a mi ICommand

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, maui

como andan? Estoy desarrollando una app movil en .NET MAUI (soy nuevo en .NET MAUI), el problema que tengo es el siguiente:

Cree un control personalizado que es una clase de "Contenedor", en donde tiene unos elementos fijos y luego se le pueden agregar dinamicamente elementos. Estos elementos dinamicos que voy agregando,  en este caso son stacklayouts con botones adentro, el problema que tengo es que estos botones no ejecutan la accion que le digo en mi viewModel. En cambio, si yo esos stack layouts con los botones dentro los pongo fuera de mi control, si funcionan, por lo tanto asumo que es un problema que debo tener dentro de mi control personalizado que cree.

Aqui va mi codigo:

COMPONENTE CONTROL PERSONALIZADO:

DashboardItemBoxView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Helpers"
             x:Class="StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Controls.DashboardItemBoxView">
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border 
                Margin="10" 
                BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding ContentViewColor}">
                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10"/>
                </Border.StrokeShape>
                <Border.Shadow>
                    <Shadow
                        Brush="{TemplateBinding ContentViewColor}"
                        Offset="0,8"
                        Opacity="0.5"               
                        Radius="50">
                    </Shadow>
                </Border.Shadow>

                <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid x:Name="titleGrid" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image 
                            WidthRequest="{TemplateBinding IconFontSize}" HeightRequest="{TemplateBinding IconFontSize}"
                            MaximumWidthRequest="50" MinimumWidthRequest="50">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <FontImageSource                                 
                                    FontFamily="{TemplateBinding IconFontFamily}"
                                    Glyph="{TemplateBinding IconFont}"             
                                    Color="{x:StaticResource IconFontColor}"/>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>

                        <Label  Grid.Column="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                FontSize="15" 
                                TextColor="{TemplateBinding TitleForeColor}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Frame Grid.Row="1">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Frame>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>

</ContentView>
```

La parte de  es donde se agrega lo que se solicita de forma dinamica.

PAGINA EN DONDE INCLUYO MI CONTROL DINAMICO

EmployeeAdministratorDashboardPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Views.General.Dashboards.EmployeeAdministratorDashboardPage"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Helpers"
             xmlns:myControls="clr-namespace:StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Controls"
             Title="Administracion"
             BackgroundColor="White">

        <Grid>
            
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="titleRow" Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="productDivisionRow" Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="productItemsRow" Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Gestion de Administrador" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="30" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Gray"/>
       
            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                <myControls:DashboardItemBoxView 
                    Title="Productos" 
                    TitleForeColor="White" 
                    ContentViewColor="{x:StaticResource StoreSysPrimaryColor}"
                    IconFont="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.InboxArrowUp}"
                    IconFontFamily="MaterialDesignIcons"
                    IconFontColor="White"
                    IconFontSize="24">

                    <HorizontalStackLayout >
                        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="5,0,0,0" >
                            <Button
                                    BackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource LigthRed}" 
                                    CornerRadius="20"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    IsEnabled="True">
                                <Button.ImageSource>
                                    <FontImageSource 
                                        FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcons"
                                        Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.PlusBox}"             
                                        Color="{x:StaticResource StoreSysPrimaryColor}"
                                        Size="20" />
                                </Button.ImageSource>

                            <Button.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding goCrudProductPageCommand}"/>
                            </Button.GestureRecognizers>
                                
                            </Button>
                            <Label 
                                    Text="Registro" 
                                    FontSize="14" 
                                    TextColor="White"/>

                        </VerticalStackLayout>

                        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="5,0,0,0">

                            <Button
                                    BackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource LigthRed}" 
                                    CornerRadius="20"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Command="{Binding goScanBarCodeProductPageCommand}">
                                <Button.ImageSource>
                                    <FontImageSource 
                                    FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcons"
                                    Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.Scanner}"             
                                    Color="{x:StaticResource StoreSysPrimaryColor}"
                                    Size="20" />
                                </Button.ImageSource>
                            </Button>

                            <Label Text="Escanear" FontSize="14" TextColor="White"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </myControls:DashboardItemBoxView>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

EmployeeAdministratorDashboardPage.cs

```
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewModels.General.Management;

namespace StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Views.General.Dashboards;

public partial class EmployeeAdministratorDashboardPage : ContentPage
{
    public EmployeeAdministratorDashboardPage(EmployeeAdministratorDashboardViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

View model de la pagina donde incluyo mi componente(control) personalizado. Aqui es donde al tocar un boton deberia ejecutarse el command, al estar dentro de mi componente personalizado el boton nunca llega a este view model, en caso de que este fuera de mi componente, si lo hace.

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Extensions;
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Services.App.Navegation;
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewModels.Shared;
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Views.Products;
using static StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewModels.Products.ScanBarCodeProductViewModel;

namespace StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewModels.General.Management
{
    public partial class EmployeeAdministratorDashboardViewModel : GlobalViewModel
    {
        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task goScanBarCodeProductPage()
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"scanOperation" , SCAN_OPERATION.READ_PRODUCT }
            };
            var uri = $"{nameof(ScanBarcodeProductPage)}";
            await ServiceLocator.GetService<INavigationService>().GoToAsync(uri, parameters);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task goCrudProductPage()
        {

            var uri = $"{nameof(CRUDProductPage)}";
            await ServiceLocator.GetService<INavigationService>().GoToAsync(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Espero ser claro y gracias de ante mano por la ayuda y atencion!